# jQuery selector on a jQuery reference

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, selector

In jQuery I select a form:

```
eSpecialForm = $('form[name="specialForm"]');
```

Then I want to select the submit button in this form. What is the proper syntax for this?

```
eSpecialSubmit = eSpecialForm.$('button[type="submit"]');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `.find()` which is the fastest method in jquery:

```
eSpecialSubmit = eSpecialForm.find('button[type="submit"]');
```

Comment: `$('button[type="submit"]', eSpecialSubmit);` would work as well.

Comment: @JustinNiessner ya, of course but .find() is the prefered method as using context will be translated using find() internally

Comment: Just wanted to point it out. Whether or not you use it is up to you.

Comment: @JustinNiessner you are right but just be aware than $('> selector',context) seems deprecated even i cannot find any official link. $(selector,context) is not deprecated of course

Answer (score 1):

You can do this -

```
eSpecialSubmit = $('button[type="submit"]',eSpecialForm);
```